# Free partition tool solves my low disk space risk

Tags: partitioning

My Windows 7 32-bit PC is running low on disk space. I want to find a useful partition manager software that can help solve this problem; I'd prefer free solutions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Windows 7's Disk Management feature? [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) is a guide for how to use it.

[image]

Comment: The built in disk manager has become surprisingly useful since Vista, and for simple partition resizes you don't need anything else.  Sometimes the data can't be moved but a bit of shuffling data to other partitions and deletion of the offending partition allows a long winded but reliable partition move in Windows, without the risk of GParted or other linux tools corrupting your partitions and forcing you to use your install cd repair it.

Comment: FWIW, I've NEVER had an issue using a gparted livecd on a Windows partition in XP, Vista, or Win7.  It's not necessarily as easy as a pre-existing app, but it's still simple and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

A partition manager only helps to cannibalize other partitions or unused space. It can't otherwise fix low disk space. Be very careful when cannibalizing other partitions, or you will find yourself reinstalling Windows.

If you want to get a bigger hard disk, then it is not a partition manager that you need, but a disk-imaging product to transfer the operating system and data. Or if you have the place for it, get a second hard disk and move your data out of the system drive.